# How to solve "301 moved permanently" in android webview?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement foursquare OAuth based authentication in my android app. It works fine in my Andorid web browser, but it displays "301 moved permanently" in Android webview. I tried to debug it and found that it displays this error on following URL:

```
https://foursquare.com/mobile/login?continue=%2Fmobile%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Foauth_token{my_token}
```

And the same URL works fine on Andriod browser. So, I think there is something need to be done with webview seetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by overriding following method:

```
 @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                SslError error) {

            handler.proceed();              
        }
```

Comment: Words of warning - this works around the problem of a invalid cert but also leaves the WebView wide open to valid SSL errors and potential attacks. Use this approach with caution or not at all. A better solution is to fix the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an invalid certificate. The certificate should be fixed on the server, not in Android.